# Execute background network tasks cyclically while being able to cancel the entire cycle

Tags: android, networking, timer, task, runnable

I am developing an app that needs to perform network tasks one-by-one in a particular order, and with a particular time in between each execution.

I have tried to implement this using AsyncTask and TimerTask.

AsyncTask won't work because to be able to cancel it I need to create an AsyncTask object, but if I do that then I can't re-launch the task upon completion.

TimerTask works to some extent, but it is extremely clunky. Trying to cancel a TimerTask mid-operation has proven to be quite difficult, and I am constantly getting two versions of my task running. This problem amplified when I tried to split the TimerTask into five smaller TimerTasks (one for each operation that needs to be completed).

So, is there any way to perform a set of background tasks, in order, with a particular time in between each execution?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class RunnableQueue {
    ArrayList<Runnable> queue;
    Runnable[] tasks;
    boolean cancelled;
    double tag;

    public RunnableQueue(Runnable... tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
        this.tag = Math.random();
        queue = new ArrayList<Runnable>();
        Collections.addAll(queue, tasks);
    }

    public void add(Runnable r) {
        queue.add(r);
    }

    public double getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void addToFront(Runnable r) {
        queue.add(0, r);
    }

    public void next() {
        if (queue.size() > 0) {
            new Thread(queue.get(0)).start();
            queue.remove(0);
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        cancelled = true;
        queue.clear();
    }

    public void resume() {
        if (cancelled) {
            tag = Math.random();
            cancelled = false;
            Collections.addAll(queue, tasks);
            next();
        }
    }

    public boolean isCancelled() {
        return cancelled;
    }
}
```

Here's an example Runnable that would work with the RunnableQueue:

```
Runnable queueTester = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        double tag = executor.getTag();

        //do some background stuff here

        Log.i("RunnableQueue-test", "queueTester complete. Sleeping...");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (executor.isCancelled()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Boolean is false. Not continuing.");
        } else if (executor.getTag() != tag) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Tag has been updated. Not continuing.");
        } else {
            executor.add(this);
            executor.next();
        }
    }
};
```